# Azure (Co-Located or Dedicated) Cache Across Cloud Services

Tags: c#, caching, azure, azure-caching

Is it possible to define certain role(s) as co-located\dedicated cache roles on Cloud Service A, and access them from roles in Cloud Service B?

(without using the Azure Shared Cache solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about Azure IaaS virtual machines and having co-located/hybrid caching with windows app fabric caching...you could do it using the Virtual Network feature to combine endpoints.

Comment: Yes it absolutely works, using the segmenting/sharding techniques you can even dictate the private and public locations of the cache in a hybrid cloud scenario.  Stability of the current virtual network environment prevented us from further considerations of this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the answer is no. I believe cache roles only expose internal endpoints, which are only accessible from within the same cloud service.